# Use filter() on a string in Swift 2

Tags: swift

I'm not sure if the API in swift 2 changed, but I can't get filter to work on a string in Swift 2. The following should change "abc123$$$ ff" into "abcff".

```
// Removes all special characters and whitespaces
func compressString(aString: String) -> String{
    let charSet = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()

// The following don't work:
//    return aString.filter{charSet.contains($0)}
//    return String(filter(aString).{charSet.contains($0)})
}
```

Comment: What's your question?  What happened if not what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use filter, you need to run it on the characters view:

```
// Removes all special characters and whitespaces
func compressString(aString: String) -> String{
    let charSet: [Character] = ["$", " ", "1", "2", "3"]

    // The following don't work:
    return String(aString.characters.filter { !charSet.contains($0) })
}

let before = "abc123$$$ ff"


let after = compressString(before) // "abcff"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func compressString(aString: String) -> String {
    let letterSet = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()
    return String(aString.characters.filter{letterSet.characterIsMember(String($0).utf16.first!)})
}

let str = "abc123$$$ ff"
compressString(str)   // abcff
```

You can also create an extension to simplify your code:

```
extension String {
    var lettersOnly: String {
        return String(characters.filter{NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet().characterIsMember(String($0).utf16.first!)})
    }
}
// Removes all special characters and whitespaces

let str = "abc123$$$ ff"

let letters = str.lettersOnly   // "abcff"
```

Comment: Works for me. But is there a way to use filter?

Comment: @goodcow You can use NSCharacterSet characterIsMember method. See my edit.